# how to get return value from a method or constructor in TS/JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, momentjs

I want to create something like momentJS where it can **return a value** with this `moment()` method and it also can have **chaining function** like `moment().add(1, 'd').timezone('Asia/Singapore').format('LLL')` or just . `moment().timezone('Asia/Singapore')`

I tried to create something like above in Javascript / Typescript using **classes**.

So, How can I get return value and chaining function within one method?.

Suppose I have method called `molent()`

```js
class Time {
  constructor () {
    this.time = '';
  }

  format (format) {
    if (format) {
      let formatResult = // some method
      this.time = formatResult;
    }
    return this;
  }

  add (n, d) {
    if (n && d) {
      let addResult = // some method
      this.time = addResult;
    }
    return this;
  }

  timezone (tz) {
    if (tz) {
      let tzResult = // some method
      this.time = tzResult;
    }
    return this;
  }
}

function molent () {
  let t = new Time()

  return t
}

molent().format();
//it returns { time: '' }
//I want it returning a value

molent();
//it returns { time, format, add, timezone }
//I want it returning a value
```

What I want is the `molent()` will return a value ex. datetime now like `moment` instead of object. and I also want the chaining function return `result` value not an object.

Comment: The instances should be objects, but you can give them *toString* and *valueOf* methods that mean they can behave like primitives. If you're trying to copy moment.js, look at the (non–minified) [source](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js).

Answer (score 0):

Add `toString()` method to your `Time` class. When you use object as string it retuns that `toString()` returned value.

```
toString() {
   return this.time;
}
```